# TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have this DatetimeIndex:

```
dates = DatetimeIndex(['2017-06-09', '2017-06-10', '2017-06-11', '2017-06-12',
               '2017-06-13', '2017-06-14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset>')
```

I want to take dates and append them to my DataFrame `df`:

```
for i in xrange(0,5):
    df.append(dates[i],ignore_index=True)
```

I get this error `TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object`.

**UPDATE:**

sample data of `df`:

```
Out[85]:
2017-06-05   -0.944868
2017-06-06    0.073623
2017-06-07   -0.687232
Freq: <DateOffset>, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If length of `df` is same as `DatetimeIndex` and need create `index`:

```
df.index = dates
```

If not try filter by length of `index` what is same as length of `df`:

```
df.index = dates[:len(df.index)]
```

If need new column:

```
df['a'] = dates
```

If not:

```
df['a'] = dates[:len(df.index)]
```

If need use only first 5 values:

```
df['a'] = dates[:5]
```

EDIT:

I think you need [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) for concatenate index to `dates` and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df = df.reindex(df.index.union(dates), fill_value=-0.944868)
print (df)
2017-06-05   -0.944868
2017-06-06    0.073623
2017-06-07   -0.687232
2017-06-09   -0.944868
2017-06-10   -0.944868
2017-06-11   -0.944868
2017-06-12   -0.944868
2017-06-13   -0.944868
2017-06-14   -0.944868
Name: <DateOffset>, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The number of rows in `df` and `dates` is different. I checked the type of `df` and indeed it's pandas Series. If I run this `df.index = dates[:len(df.index)]`, then the content of `df` gets substituted by `dates`, while I need to append it.

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: I added a sample data. In `df` the dates are indices.

Comment: As values I want to put some constant, e.g. `-0.944868`, for all appended entries from `dates`.