# return the value which is most repeated by a sequence given as input

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Am trying get the most watched rating of a new user with his particulars, like age, gen, mar_sta and occ ...

Dataset :

```
user    age gender  mar_sta occ rating
A   Young   M   married eng     PG13
B   adult   M   married doc      R
C   teen    M   single  clerk   NR
D   old     M   married retired  U
E   Young   F   married eng    PG13
F   adult   F   married doc     R
G   teen    F   single  clerk   NR
H   old     F   married retired U
I   Young   M   single  eng    PG13
J   adult   M   single  doc     R
K   teen    M   single  clerk   NR
L   old     M   single  retired U
M   Young   F   single  eng    PG13
N   adult   F   single  doc     R
O   teen    F   single  clerk   NR
P   old     F   single  retired U
```

Thats my database which I have, and am sending a new user's data and trying to find the most watched rating by that sequence.

New User:

```
user age gender mar_sta  occ rating
X   teen   M    single   clerk  ?
Y    Nan   F    single    eng    ?
```

I am trying to assign the rating for the new user using my data set. There are null values in the data, so  I have to ignore the null value and consider which ever values are there and assign the rating.

For user Y, I have nan for age.. so my code should ignore age variable and consider only `gender`, `mar_sta`, `occ` and find the `most watched rating`.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
X : NR
Y : PG13
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should give you a basic starting point for what you are trying to do. It will return the correct 'most-watched rating' for that user, based on the other columns.

```
df = < your dataframe >

age_val = 'teen'
gender_val = 'M'
mar_sta = 'single'
occ = 'clerk'

frames = []

if age_val != None:
    age = df.groupby(['age', 'rating']).rating.count()['teen']
    frames.append(age)

if gender_val != None:
    gender = df.groupby(['gender', 'rating']).rating.count()['M']
    frames.append(gender)

if mar_sta != None:
    mar_sta = df.groupby(['mar_sta', 'rating']).rating.count()['single']
    frames.append(mar_sta)

if occ != None:
    occ = df.groupby(['occ', 'rating']).rating.count()['clerk']
    frames.append(occ)

result_table = pd.concat(frames).groupby(level=0).sum().fillna(0)
result_rating = result_table.idxmax()
```

You will need to add code to pull the various fields from 'User X' in your table, as well as set the variables at the start to None if they are NaN/invalid. You will then need to set User X's rating field using the value in `result_rating`.

Comment: I do see frames consist of all individual ratings of users x variables, that means, rating given by teen, M, single, clerk,  individually, but cant I group by with all four ? age, gender, mar_sta and occ ?

Comment: This dont seem to work `result_table = pd.concat(frames).groupby(level=0).sum().fillna(0)` .... says  `TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object`

Comment: This works fine for the input dataset you gave in the question.. I'm not sure what your other dataframes look like. Perhaps have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167175/typeerror-cannot-concatenate-a-non-ndframe-object).